# Displaying a parent template in child template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, cordova, ember.js

I'm working to create a master view cordova/javascript application where a user a presented with a list of products, then depending on what they select, got to a tabbed based detail page about the product. Each tab will be generated depending on which product they pick. Along with the product specific information being loaded, I still want to keep a list a all the products in the view so that a user could switch products when ever they want. Here's an image to help better understand what I'm talking about. [image].

I tried to use ember.js to get this up and running but ran into a few issues. I can get the initial list of products generated and switch to the product specific details, but once I try to load the master list of products in my second template, everything breaks. I know about including two templates with an `{{outlet}}` in the parent template but I cant get this to have the child inherit the parent. Is this possible to do in ember or should I start looking at other frameworks like Anuglar? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying nested templates is actually where Ember has an advantage over other frameworks, in my opinion.

This should be really simple using nested resources. In your router, you can do something like

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('products', function() {
    this.route('product', { path: '/product_id' });
  });
});
```

Obviously, you'll have to fetch your data in each corresponding route. Something like

```
App.ProductsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    this.store.find('product');
  }
});

App.ProductsProductRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    this.store.find('product', params.product_id);
  }
});
```

In your `product` template you'll need to include an `{{outlet}}` for all child routes to render into (ie, `products.product`).

For example

**product.handlebars**

```
{{#each}}
  {{name}}
{{/each}}

{{outlet}}
```

**products/product.handlebars**

```
Product: {{id}}
```

Check out the resources section [in the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/).

---

**EDIT**

If you want the master list to display differently between the `products` template and the `products.product` template, remove the master list from the `products` template and put it in the `products.index` *and* the `products.product` template.

Then specify that both the `ProductsIndexController` and the `ProductsProductController` `needs` its parent model. This will give both templates access to the products via `controllers.products`.

```
App.ProductsIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'products',
  products: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.products')
});

App.ProductsProductController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'products',
  products: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.products')
});
```

See [this jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/udAhUWi/1/) and the [associated guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

Comment: Yes I know about this method, which is why I chose to use ember. But the method you're describing is if I wanted the master list to be formatted the same way through out the entire app. For my Products Template there would be one style and for my Product template it would styled differently. So If I tried to load the data in my second template, ember gets "confused" as to which data it should display and wont load both sets of data.

Comment: One last question. I saw you added ember data. Is this going to be a requirement or is this just a choice that you made to include it?

Comment: ember-data is not required for this to work. The main point is to call `needs` from within whatever controller needs access to all the products.